# 301 redirect through web.config for Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, web-config, redirect

I'm attempting to do simple 301 page directs through web.config, but for some reason it isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
              </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="index_1.html">
      <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://newurl.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please check this : http://www.dantor.com/support/misc/web-config-response-redirect.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Checked it out and tried to implement, but it didn't work. I'm assuming it has something to do with GoDaddy. I asked their tech about this redirect functionality, but they couldn't provide any solution.

Comment: Did you solve this problem, I have similar problem and I can't archieve this